# TeamViewer bypass OpenVPN

Tags: windows, openvpn, teamviewer

I have computer with installed TeamViewer and connected to the VPN.

Since this client redirects traffic through its servers and the VPN server is located in CN, the data transfer rate is very small.

I want TeamViewer to connect directly (**bypass VPN**). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You would need to either find the TeamViewer server range(s) and add routes to push those directly put the network interface or use policy based routing and push traffic out based on port.